# How do you do wildcard subdomains?

Tags: .htaccess

I want subdomain.example.com to point to example.com/profile.php?user=subdomain

With "subdomain" varying with user input

How do you do that? Also, I want it to be a silent redirect, so the subdomain.example.com is shown in the adress bar when the user types it or clicks on a link

Answer (score 8):

See this one: http://www.easymodrewrite.com/example-subdomains
You will actually need

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +Indexes
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.domain.com$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).domain.com [NC]
   RewriteRule (.*) domain.com/profile.php?user=%2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

EDIT: to have a "silent" redirect, the last rule should be:

```
   RewriteRule (.*) /profile.php?user=%2 [L]
```

Make sure you have the `profile.php` in the directory where the `DocumentRoot` of the wildcard is set to.

Comment: Thanks, that sort of worked except when I type in the URL it does a physical redirect instead of a silent one

What I want is for the subdomain to remain in the address bar so the users won't know theres a redirect

Comment: @Ryan, then you can call the "profile.php" from your subdomain, e.g. make `http://user1.domain.com` equal to calling `http://user1.domain.com/profile.php?user=user1`
Edited my post to describe the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've not done this myself, but I'd start by:

1. With your DNS provider, configure the wildcard.

   `*.domain.com.    IN   A    1.2.3.4`
2. Use Apache's `mod_rewrite` to inspect the Host: header and modify the URL to match your specs.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is probably a mix of all the mentioned solutions.

First you will need the DNS entries as mentioned by JJ. Then you have to use the [ServerAlias directive](http://www.smokinglinux.com/apache-tutorials/apache-alias-configuration-with-serveralias) to make all subdomains pointing to the same directory. And at the end you could use the first 2 lines of Niek Bergman's code:

```
$domain = explode(".", $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
$username = htmlentities($domain[0]);
```

And from there on you can do with $username whatever you want.